# Use a file token for directory path when uploading a file via core file upload field?

Tags: 8, tokens, files

Is there a way to use a token like `[file:fid]` when using the file upload field? I either want to use this, or, use the node id it is attached to with `[node:nid]`. It looks like I can only use global tokens, which are not unique enough to the way I want to store the file on the server.

Answer (score 4):

In core this is not possible, because the file widget sets the #upload_location when it builds the form element.

You need a module, for example [File (Field) Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths). This module sets a temp path in #upload_location of the form element and sorts this out later when the file and node entity are available.